# Does cucumber have a way to disable javascript in a single Scenario (where the parent Feature is marked @javascript)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

My Rails app has a cucumber Feature that is tagged `@javascript`, thus all Scenarios in the Feature will use JS.

But I have one edge case that I want to check, and it requires javascript to be disabled.  (I'm testing a failsafe in case some JS error-checking fails.)

Can I disable JS for just one Scenario in Feature?  Creating a separate Feature file seems kinda silly.

It'd be really great if there was a `@nojavascript` tag, but that doesn't appear to be a thing.